# How do I sort a List of Dictionaries based on the length of a list in each Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I am working on an API based on GoT. I have retrieved a list of dictionaries (of each character) that contain different values based on the keys.

I am attempting to sort the entire list by the length of the "titles" list in descending order. This would help me retrieve the top ten characters with the most titles more efficiently. How would I implement this with a sorting method in Python 3?

The code below is a small snippet of how the List of Character Dictionaries looks. As you can see, I have two dictionaries within the list and within each dictionary, the key "title" has a value of a list of strings. In this case, Alyssa Velaryon has more titles than Jon Snow based on the length of the "titles" list.

```
[ #List of Characters

    { #Start of Jon Snow's Dictionary
        "name": "Jon Snow",
        "titles": [
            "Lord Commander of the Night's Watch"
        ]#List of titles 
    } #End of Jon Snow's Dictionary

    { #Start of Alyssa Velaryon's Dictionary
        "name":"Alyssa Velaryon",
        "titles":["Lady","Queen","Dowager Queen","Queen
            Regent", "Lady of Storm's End"]# List of titles
    } #End of Alyssa Velaryon's Dictionary

]#End of Character List
```

Answer (score 3):

Provide an appropriate sort key function, e.g.:

```
list_of_chars.sort(key=lambda d: len(d.get('titles', [])), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_len_of_titles(d):
    return -len(d['titles'])

character_list.sort(key=reverse_len_of_titles)
```

Using the "key" of the sort function this is quite easy. Note the `-` for descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Other option using built in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sorted), let the original list as it is:

```
res = sorted(list_of_chars, key=lambda x: len(x['titles']), reverse=True )
print(res)

#=> [{'name': 'Alyssa Velaryon', 'titles': ['Lady', 'Queen', 'Dowager Queen', 'QueenRegent', "Lady of Storm's End"]}, {'name': 'Jon Snow', 'titles': ["Lord Commander of the Night's Watch"]}]
```